# How to solve this system of equations?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, equation

I have a set of n equations of the form :

[image]

where the c_i's are floating point constants. I want to solve this system of equations.

This system can be reduced to the matrix form of Ax = [O], where the solution x is the null space of the matrix.

Below is the procedure for generating the matrix from the given c_i's.

```
n = len(c)
m = []
for i in xrange(n):
    coef = []
    for j in xrange (n):
        if i == j :
            coef.append(c[i]-1)
        else :
            coef.append(c[i])
    m.append(coef)
    A = matrix(m)
```

For non-trivial solutions to exist, we need that the determinant of this matrix be non-zero, which is not the case always.

**One way to make the determinant zero is to make the last row of the matrix zero.** By doing this, we get all the x_i's correctly except for the last one. Below is the code for the same :

```
import scipy
from scipy import linalg, matrix

def null(A, eps=1e-15):
    u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A)
    null_mask = (s <= eps)
    null_space = scipy.compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
    return scipy.transpose(null_space)

def solve_for_values(c):
    n = len(c)
    m = []
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        coef = []
        for j in xrange (n):
            if i == j :
                coef.append(c[i]-1)
            else :
                coef.append(c[i])
        m.append(coef)
    z = [0 for _ in xrange(n)]
    m.append(z)
    A = matrix(m)
    return null(A)
# Testing   
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    c_array = [0.037105,0.548525,0.102255,0.008687,0.203427]
    x = solve_for_values(c_array)
    print x
    for item in x :
        print item/sum(x)
```

**Output :**

```
[0.037105,0.548525,0.102255,0.008687,0.303428]
```

Note that the 1st four values match with `c_array` in the code, except for the last one.

Is this the best we can do ? I am also open to approximate solutions.

Comment: If you sum the equations you get 1 on the lhs and the sum of the c[i] on the right, so the sum of the c[i] must be 1. If x1..xn is a solution, so is a*x1..a*xn for any non zero a. We can choose a so that the sum of the x[i] is 1, and then we get a solution x[i] = c[i], i=1..n, and the other solutions are multiples of this.

Comment: When you say "solve", what do you mean? As @dmuir pointed out, an exact solution is only possible if the c_i values sum to unity. In the example you gave, this is not the case and so no exact solution exists. To find the optimal non-exact solution, you'll have to specify some kind of cost function that you'd like to minimize, rather than a simple equality.